# json-server-auth for angular guarded routes not working using postman

Tags: json, angular

I have a problem now with json-auth-server using the guarded routes in angular.

I wanted to add a guarded route on some location in my db but testing it with the postman application showed that the guarded root does not work.

I added the 600 key in the routes.json file which is: User must own the resource to write or read the resource.

In this way in the postman application in order to access the guarded db route i have to use a key parameter Authorization with value Bearer+accessToken in order to access that route.

In my case it does not work - i can access the guarded route without adding parameters.

Can someone tell me what can be the problem here?

Just to be clear i added the routes.json file in my application and added the needed parameters in json code for my routes that have to be guarded..

Can you please help me?

db.json file contents

```html
{
  "users": [
    {
      "email": "olivier@mail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$t7tcm61VhhmWnk5U1oWN0.6SF4/.DUZuSKqBNqt06/mVnGYijmLO6",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "email": "wtf@mail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$2clz7R/P7hq41RLcg6P.2.PB3yzlJ.q/i47vQpEw0UCYjURk0owiK",
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "posts": [
    {
      "title": "Anther post title.",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Dolore magna aliqua.",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And the routes.json file contents:

```html
{
"users": 400,
"posts": 660
}
```

Also here it is the postman request that gets the database data without adding the needed parameters so it can access the guarded route

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I use (got it from the docs)
`npx json-server-auth db.json -r routes.json`
It worked as showed in the below image
[image]

As you can see the routes and their's guards are all listed. If you don't see the same, kindly `restart` your server.

PS: I see in your picture, the headers tab in postman has 6 indicating that the headers aren't empty. So you could try by entering the url directly in browsers.

Comment: yes the server works but the routes stated in the server should not open unless you send a the accessToken as a parameter in the postman application.. They open anyway, that is the problem.. I tried restarting the server but i still get the same results in postman and in the browser.. That is the problem that the routes must not be accessible unless a parameter  accessToken is sent in the post request..